# Why does it say "expected an indented block?"

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

class Coords:
    def __init__(self, x1=0, y1=0, x2=0, y2=0):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2

    def within_x(co1, co2):
        if co1.x1 > co2.x1 and co1.x1 < co2.x1:
            return True
        elif co1.x2 > co2.x1 and co1.x2 < co2.x2:
            return True
        elif co2.x1 > co1.x1 and co2.x1 < co1.x1:
            return True
        elif co2.x2 > co1.x1 and co2.x2 < co1.x1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def within_y(co1, co2):
        if (co1.y1 > co2.y1 and co1.y1 < co2.y2) \
           or (co1.y2 > co2.y1 and co1.y2 < co2.y2)\
           or (co2.y1 > co1.y1 and co2.y1 < co1.y1) \
           or (co2.y2 > co1.y1 and co2.y2 < co1.y1):

        return True
    else: 
        return False


    def collided_right(co1, co2):
        if wi1thin_y(co1, co2):
            if  co1.x2 >= co2.x1 and co1.x2 <= co2.x2:
                return True
            return False

class Game:
    def __init__(self):

        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Mr. Stick Man Races for the Exit")
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, \
                             highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.canvas_height = 500
        self.canvas_width = 500
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="backround.gif")
        w = self.bg.width()
        h = self.bg.height()
        for x in range(0, 5):
            for y in range(0, 5):
                self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, \
                                         image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
        self.sprites = []
        self.Running = True
 
    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.Running == True:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprite.move()
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(0.01)
            
g = Game()
g.mainloop()
```

It says expected an indented block at line 30:

```
    def within_y(co1, co2):
        if (co1.y1 > co2.y1 and co1.y1 < co2.y2) \
           or (co1.y2 > co2.y1 and co1.y2 < co2.y2)\
           or (co2.y1 > co1.y1 and co2.y1 < co1.y1) \
           or (co2.y2 > co1.y1 and co2.y2 < co1.y1):

        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

Where should it be indented?

Comment: The `return True` block is not indented properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def within_y(co1, co2):
    if (co1.y1 > co2.y1 and co1.y1 < co2.y2) \
       or (co1.y2 > co2.y1 and co1.y2 < co2.y2)\
       or (co2.y1 > co1.y1 and co2.y1 < co1.y1) \
       or (co2.y2 > co1.y1 and co2.y2 < co1.y1):

        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here return is called exactly down line of if statement ex.
If statement: #here is if statement
return True # here you are calling return

It should be like
If statement:
return true
else statement:
Return false

Here is your code
[image]

Comment: Please answer the code with text. if not, we have to type all your answer code